Using 8192 samples and denoising (0.05 threshold) and still get noisy/blotchy renders in the shadows
It's in a night scene at 4K resolution, on a terrace lit by wall fixtures and an night hdri.
I see people putting 1000 samples max and get clean results. How can I have 8192 samples with denoise and still get blotchy/artifacted/noisy shadows?
Can you help understand how to get rid of the noise?
Thank you in advance.
